# How to validate Cox Proportional Hazards model?

Tags: cross-validation, survival, cox-model, validation

I'm using a Cox proportional Hazards regression (R *survival* package) to model Credit card activation propension, ie, which people are more likely to make their first buy? To give more context: [Defining target variable - Credit Card industry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233145/defining-target-variable-credit-card-industry).

So I have:

*birth*: Credit card creation

*death*: Date of first buy

*event*: people use their card for the first time

Here's the model summary:

```
## Call:
## coxph(formula = Surv(TIME, EVENT) ~ IDADE_EMPRESA + ZERO_RATIO + 
##     AVG_VENDAS + UF_CE + UF_ES + UF_DF + VL_LIMITE_COMPRA_ORIGINAL + 
##     VL_LIMITE_PARCEIRO + SD_VENDAS, data = x)
## 
##   n= 32548, number of events= 1999 

## Concordance= 0.716  (se = 0.007 )
## Rsquare= 0.038   (max possible= 0.706 )
## Likelihood ratio test= 1252  on 9 df,   p=0
## Wald test            = 1326  on 9 df,   p=0
## Score (logrank) test = 1318  on 9 df,   p=0
```

What I have done so far: used 9 months of data to fit the model and 3 remaining months as a holdout validation set. Now, I'm not sure how to use the validation set, what I would like to do is the following:

- Rank the clients who are more likely to buy **within** 30,60,90 days (ie, I don't want the the Survival estimation T > 30,60,90), then estimate AUC or Concordance index for each time period.

Is that even possible? What are the alternatives for reporting accuracy? I have checked http://dni-institute.in/blogs/cox-regression-interpret-result-and-predict/, but it seems they are doing the opposite of what I need.

NOTE: Survival analysis is new to me, but I'm well familiar with general ML concepts like Cross Validation, Overfitting and so on. Thanks!

EDIT1: I've found the *survAUC* package, but I'm not sure if i understood the parameters:

```
  train = get.data(is.train=TRUE)
  test =  get.data(is.train=FALSE)

  fit = fit.surv() # get coxph model

  surv.train = Surv(train$TIME, train$EVENT)
  surv.test = Surv(test$TIME, test$EVENT)
  lp = predict(fit, test)
  # returns 0.7270601 0.7272526 0.7274083
  AUC.cd(surv.train, surv.test, predict(fit), predict(fit, test), c(30, 60, 90))
```

EDIT2: Another option, *survConcordance* in the survival package:

```
  fit = fit.surv()
  test =  get.data(is.train=FALSE)
  surv.test = Surv(test$TIME, test$EVENT)

  survConcordance(surv.test ~ predict(fit, test), data = test)

 # Outputs
   n= 428 
   Concordance= 0.7799616 se= 0.03275571
   concordant discordant  tied.risk  tied.time   std(c-d) 
   23533.00    6639.00       0.00     144.00    1976.61
```

I'm really not sure about what these lines above are doing, I appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 7):

This is not what you do to validate an event time model.  You need a smooth calibration curve at each of a series of time horizons plus validation of predictive discrimination, e.g., Somers' Dxy rank correlation (c-index).  The R `rms` package makes this easy, and it can use the bootstrap to correct for overfitting if you are honest about including all *candidate* variables in the model.  See my course notes for details: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms

Comment: So I cannot access how well the model predicts/ranks deaths **before** some time T? Can you explain to me what *AUC.cd* does?

Comment: @Frank Harrell, the OP is not trying to validate an event time model, he is trying to best use the data (as suggested in page 9 of your bookregression modelling strategies) .. ie he is interested in survival up to certain timeframes ( and probably wants to compare/benchmark  against a logistic regression approach)

Comment: @seanv507 Yes, I'm very new to Survival analysis as explained, I'm even considering doing a Logistic Regression for each period, but I also would like to learn more about Survival models.

Comment: One who is interested in survival probability for a certain time frame $[0,t]$ is interested in whether the model is well calibrated for predicting the probability that the event occurs later than time $t$.  And it is not appropriate to use logistic regression for time-to-event data.  That would not be efficient nor would it handle variable follow-up time.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, logistic regression doesn't seem appropriate.  Meanwhile I'll try to understand 'calibrate.cph'.